# peewee manytomany - object a id and object b id on through table causes integrity error

Tags: python, many-to-many, peewee, data-integrity

I am trying to save Tags within a Path to a through-table using a manytomany relationship, where Path is a list of Tags where tag might be a duplicate, like this:

```
path = ['div', 'div', 'div', 'div', 'div', 'ul', 'li', 'a']
```

If the Path above has an ID of 1, and I am storing Tags with a unique constraint, I expect the following in the through-table:

- path_id    |    tag_id
- 1______ 1
- 1______ 1
- 1______ 1
- 1______ 1
- 1______ 1
- 1______ 2
- 1______ 3
- 1______ 4

Where tag_id's 1,2,3 and 4 are `div`, `ul`, `li` and `a` respectively.

However, I get the following error:

```
peewee.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: path_tag_through.path_id, path_tag_through.tag_id
```

What exactly am I doing wrong here? I can't set `unique=False` either.

Here is the code to replicate:

```
import peewee
from peewee import *
db = SqliteDatabase('bs.db')

class BaseModel(Model):
    class Meta:
        database = db

class Tag(BaseModel):
    name = CharField()

class Path(BaseModel):
    name = CharField()
    tags = ManyToManyField(Tag, backref='path')

PathTags = Path.tags.get_through_model()

db.create_tables([
    Tag,
    Path,
    PathTags])

my_path = ['div', 'div', 'div', 'div', 'div', 'ul', 'li', 'a']

path_id = Path.insert(name='my_path').execute()

path_obj = Path.get(path_id)

for i in my_path:
    path_obj.tags.add(i)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The many-to-many field assumes that the two foreign-keys comprising the relationship are unique. If you looked at the source code you'd see that there's a unique constraint on the two fks in the thru table. Your example is weird because you aren't talking about a set of relations but an ordering of things that you've normalized into a separate table for some insane reason (tag). In short, this is over-engineered all to hell.

If you insist on this schema, then create the through table explicitly without the unique constraint. You probably want to add a third column to specify the ordering, since it seems to be meaningful in your example.

Also your code is inefficient. Just do:

```
path_obj = Path.create(name='my_path')
path_obj.tags.add(my_path)
```

Comment: By storing tag values in its own table with unique=True, I can avoid encoding tag values later down the line by just using tag ids from the through table. That's the theory anyway, I'm just testing it out